# MySQL LEFT JOIN example with conditions

Tags: mysql

I am using following query to retrieve the needed objects:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_po_items
LEFT JOIN tb_materials ON tb_po_items.po_material = tb_materials.id_material
LEFT JOIN tb_services ON tb_po_items.po_service = tb_services.id_service
WHERE po_id =47
```

Now I need to add following:

Condition 1 -> if tb_po_items.mos = 1 then LEFT JOIN tb_units ON tb_materials.material_unit = tb_units.id_unit

else

Condition 2 -> if tb_po_items.mos = 2 then LEFT JOIN tb_units ON tb_services.service_unit = tb_units.id_unit

How can I implement the use of both conditions in the MySQL query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik, yes, of course. Table tb_po_items includes values related to tb_materials and tb_services. Both tables, tb_materials and tb_services have a field related to tb_units. The result I am trying to achieve is the value from tb_units.unit_name depending on the value of tb_po_items.mos

Comment: @Mureinik, If you need real data from the tables or the tables structures, I could put them on my question.

Comment: Try this:
`SELECT *
FROM tb_po_items
LEFT JOIN tb_materials ON tb_po_items.po_material = tb_materials.id_material
LEFT JOIN tb_services ON tb_po_items.po_service = tb_services.id_service
WHERE po_id =47
LEFT JOIN tb_units ON (
  (tb_materials.material_unit = tb_units.id_unit AND tb_po_items.mos = 1)
  OR
  (tb_services.service_unit = tb_units.id_unit AND tb_po_items.mos = 2)
)` and let us know what happens.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax, ,thanks but you have just put the same query as in my question :)

Comment: Sorry; there was a premature save there.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax, thank you, I will check it now.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax, it works, thank you. But the WHERE clause must be put at the end of the query. Would you please put this as an answer to my question? I would be glad marking it as accepted answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Right; I overlooked the WHERE clause when I was copypasting your original query. :-[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_po_items
LEFT JOIN tb_materials ON tb_po_items.po_material = tb_materials.id_material
LEFT JOIN tb_services ON tb_po_items.po_service = tb_services.id_service
LEFT JOIN tb_units ON (
  (tb_materials.material_unit = tb_units.id_unit AND tb_po_items.mos = 1)
OR
  (tb_services.service_unit = tb_units.id_unit AND tb_po_items.mos = 2) )
WHERE po_id =47;
```

Answer (score 1):

hi this is experimental so check before you go live.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_po_items
IF(tb_po_items.mos = 1, LEFT JOIN tb_materials ON tb_po_items.po_material = tb_materials.id_material, LEFT JOIN tb_services ON tb_po_items.po_service = tb_services.id_service)
WHERE po_id =47
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay, but where to find tb_units on your proposal?

Comment: Try this may be this once helps.

SELECT * FROM tb_po_items
LEFT JOIN tb_materials ON tb_po_items.po_material = tb_materials.id_material
LEFT JOIN tb_services ON tb_po_items.po_service = tb_services.id_service
IF(tb_po_items.mos = 1, LEFT JOIN tb_units ON tb_materials.material_unit = tb_units.id_unit, LEFT JOIN tb_units ON tb_services.service_unit = tb_units.id_unit)
WHERE po_id =47

You have basic idea from above queris so do some changes in it and you will surly success.

Comment: Thank you @Ajay, your answer is good for me, but Darwin put his proposal first.. Thank you in any case.